# Change taxonomy key of existing and future taxonomy posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I registered a taxonomy with a certain key name, `initial_name`, and now there are hundreds of posts in a custom post type with this taxonomy selected that I don't want to lose the connection with (the taxonomy is selected through ACF in each of those posts)

```
register_taxonomy('initial_name', 'post', args);
```

How would I update the existing posts and future posts with a new name? `new_name`, like below

```
register_taxonomy('new_name', 'post', args);
```